# How to find the largest Ethereum token holders on a given day?

Tags: bitcoin

Here is the [Bitcoin Rich List](https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html). Is there something similar for Ethereum?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that info from etherscan

https://etherscan.io/accounts/1